# $f(x,y,z)=z^2x+e^z+y$, implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, implicit-function-theorem

$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y,z)=z^2x+e^z+y$

1. Show that a neighboorhood $V$ of $(1,-1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a continuous differentiable function $g:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(1,-1)=0$ and $f(x,y,g(x,y))=0$ for $(x,y) \in V$ exists.
2. Calculate $D_1g(1,-1)$ and $D_2g(1,-1)$

---

$\nabla f(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}
f_x\\
f_y\\
f_z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
z^2\\
1\\
e^z+2zx
\end{pmatrix}$

1. I just have to show that $f(1,-1,0)=0$ and $f_z(1,-1,0) \ne 0$, the implicit function theorem shows that it holds.
   $f(1,-1,0)=0^2+e^0-1=0$ and $f_z(1,-1,0)=e^0+0=1\neq0$
2. I know that I have to differentiate $0=xg(x,y)^2+e^{g(x,y)}+y$ with respect to $x$ and $y$. But how do I do that?

Comment: I believe you upvoted my answer as well as accepted it. I appreciate it, but I need a zero-scored accepted answer as I'm tracking for unsung-hero badge. Would you please undo your upvote? I hope you don't mind. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

By [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Case_of_f(g1(x),_..._,_gk(x))), \begin{align} 0 &=\frac {\partial}{\partial x}f(x, y, g(x, y)) \\&=   \left( f_x, f_y, f_z\right) \cdot \left(1, 0, D_1g(x,y)\right)\end{align}

Thus $f_x(1,-1,0)+ f_z(1,-1,0)D_1g(1, -1)=0$.